# How do I find a system executable path with install4j?

Tags: install4j

I am new to *install4j* and want to know the best way to find the path to an existing program on the system I am installing to so that I can run it in a later installer step. Is there an action meant for this purpose? An example might be I want to find an installed version of *javaws* so I can uninstall an application that was previously installed under WebStart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the install4j method `WinRegistry.getValue` to retrieve the location of *javaws* from the registry in a "set a variable" action to accomplish this.